# Laravel 5: How can a dropdown be showing the selected value that the page loads initially

Tags: laravel, select, drop-down-menu

I'm using Laravel and I have a dropdown which fills its options from the database on load page and another text field.

Then on the submit I validate the text field to avoid empty entries, the validation is based on the request validator from Laravel. The validation is made correctly.

The problem is that when the validation is completed (it doesn't submit because i keep the text field empty) it returns to the page, but the dropdown remains selected with the last selection by the user, but in the back(sourcecode), its selected the original value that was loaded originally.

I want that the `selectedIndex` is the one original from the load page, not the last one selected. I tried with javascript but I had no luck change in it since it's already as the `selectedIndex`, but to the user, it still showing the other option. If I refresh manually it still showing the selected one incorrectly, I need to enter the URL manually so it shows correctly.

What could be a good approach to solve this "visual" issue?

Here is the controller code

```
public function update($user_id,GuardarBancoRequest $request)
{
   $cuenta = user::whereId($user_id)->first();

   $cuenta->nombrecompleto =  Input::get('completo');
     $temp =  Input::get('tipo');
     $cuenta->tipocuenta =  Input::get('tipo');
     $temp1 =  Input::get('banco');


     if ($temp == "1") {
         $cuenta->cuentaclabe = Input::get('clabehidden');
         $cuenta->cuentatarjeta = Input::get('cuentahidden');
     } else {
          $cuenta->cuentatarjeta = Input::get('cuentahidden');
          $cuenta->cuentaclabe = Input::get('clabehidden');
     }

     if ( $temp1 == "10") {
         $cuenta->otrobanco = Input::get('otro');
         $cuenta->banco = "10";
      } else {
         $cuenta->banco = Input::get('banco');
         $cuenta->save();
      }
    return Redirect::route('bancos.show',array(Auth::user()->id));
}
```

The dropdown that I'm referring is the [tipo] one

Comment: When asking a question that has related code, please post that code as well.

Comment: The code is correct, is showing selected the right index in the code, but in visually is showing another option, not sure if is cache.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to presume without getting a chance to look at your code, but it sounds like when you do a redirect after validation you have something like 
`return redirect()->back()->withInput();` which causes fields to be prepopulated with the values entered earlier on the page. Remove `withInput()` portion in your controller if you have this.
Otherwise please mind posting your code in addition to your question, that would be helpful. (the controller part with the redirection and the view where you have the dropdown)